# remove all characters after pattern in text file

Tags: regex, vim

I have a text file with thousands of lines of text. Each line ends like

```
\\server\share\file.txt -> information
```

I want to remove everything following the space after the end of the file extension. So everything after " ->" (there's a space after the first quote)

How would you do this? I'd like to use vim as I am trying to understand more about it, but any program will do; I'd like to get this done soon.

Comment: May be able to use `(?!\.\w{2,3})(\s->\s\w+)$` to find the trailing text, though not familiar with [vim's regex](http://vimregex.com/) enough to make a "Execute this line" sort of solution.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your description is contradictory.

1. "everything following the space after the end of the file extension"
2. "So everything after " ->" (there's a space after the first quote)"

Did you want to keep the arrow or not?

1 is simply accomplished with:

```
:%s/ ->.*/
```

and actually if you really did want to keep the space before the arrow, like you said, it would be:

```
:%s/ ->.*/ /
```

2 can be done with:

```
:%s/\( ->\).*/\1/
```

If you prefer to view the results of your search before the replace you can build your search first using /:

```
/\( ->\).*
```

This will highlight all results to make sure you are replacing the right thing. You can then execute the replace command with an empty search term to use the last search (the stuff thats highlighted).

```
:%s//\1/
```

Comment: No, 2. is valid only when patterns are “very magic”. You need `\(` and `\)` for that.

Comment: You're right. I did say two different things. Sorry about that. Typing while listening to someone jabber about how stupid the police are. :/

Comment: Benoit, right you are. They were there, but they got dropped by the htmlizer and I didn't notice that. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to keep the arrow:

```
:%s/ ->\zs .*//
```

If you want to delete it:

```
:%s/ -> .*//
```

Answer (score 1):

Positive lookahead might work, something like `/(?= ->).*/` to match and replacing with emptiness.

Comment: Vim lookbehind assertion is `\@<=`. Example: `:%s/\( -> \)\@<=.*//`. Also see `:help /\@<=`.

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily done using splitting method. Since your lines are all the same, and have a special arrow `->` sign, split on that, and get the first element

```
awk -F"->" '{print $1}' file
```

Redirect to a new file if desired.

Answer (score 0):

Globally replace

```
 -> .*
```

with the empty string

(I am assuming that you want to remove the `->` even though you said "after.")